# Scope issue in TCL list

Tags: scope, tcl, procedure

I am having a list globally declared.

```
global triaAXCord 
set triAXCord {}
```

a procedure setCordinates appending values to this list.

```
proc setCordinates {AX} {
lappend triAXCord $AX
puts "$triAXCord"
}
```

that puts gives the value inserted.
But from other procedures when $triAXCord is printed as blank list. Since the list is globally declared why the values are not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the proc definition, your `triAXCord` variable is already at the global scope.  No need to explicity declare it as belonging to the global scope.

Within the proc, you are in the proc's scope and cannot access the global scope's variable unless you make it explicit within the proc.   That's different than Python where functions can access global variables by default.

Either of these two methods works *within the proc*:

1. `global triAXCord`.  This allows you to use `triAXCord` as a variable name in the proc.
2. Use the `::` prefix before the variable name, like `lappend ::triAXCord $AX`.

You could also use `upvar` if you need more flexibility in variable names or scopes.

Comment: Good advice. One bit of clarification -- `::` isn't really a "prefix", it's the namespace delimiter. The global namespace is named `""` (the empty string), so `$::triAXCord` is the value of the variable triAXCord which is in the global namespace. Ref http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm particularly [QUALIFIED NAMES](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M25)